# Laravel - updating a field on a relational table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `users` table, an `emails` table and a `user_email` table. In that join table I have the `user_id`, `email_id` and  `is_confirm`(boolean). When a user confirms his email, I want to update that field, and have tried to do so using the following methods:

In the `User` model :

```
public function emails() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Email', 'user_email')->withPivot('is_confirm');
}
```

In the `Email` model :

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_email')->select(['user_email.is_confirm', 'user_email.id']);
}
```

I have tried:

```
$emailID = Email::where('email', $email)->first();
$pivot = Email::find($emailID->id)->users->first();
$pivot->is_confirm = 1;
$pivot->save();
```

and I have also tried:

```
$emailID = Email::where('email', $email)->first();
$emailID->users()->updateExistingPivot( $emailID->user_id, ['is_confirm' => 1] );
```

However, neither option works.

Do both of my model's relations look right? How can I go about updating this field?

Comment: Your table is `users_emails` but in your relating methods, you have `user_email`.  And I think `updateExistingPivot()` is what you want.

Comment: Edited my text to set the proper table name. Also, I tried to use `updateExistingPivot` but with no success !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is as follows:

```
User::find(1)->emails()->updateExistingPivot($emailId, ['is_confirm' => 1]);
```

But I am curious if there is any reason this `is_confirm` cannot be on the email table? Additionally, as mentioned below, if an email can only by tied to one user, consider moving the foreign key `user_id` directly on to the email table along with the `is_confirm`.

Comment: That's a good point, it makes sense a user can have many emails but can one email have many users?  Perhaps this is the wrong relationship all together.

Comment: @user3158900 is completely right, unless an email can be tied to multiple users you should also consider moving `user_id` from the join directly to the email table.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answer, it worked like a charm. Actually an email CAN be tied to multiple users for us, so well, this is the right relationship :)

Comment: Since I have you here, I would also like to ask, how would I replace `$emailID->user_id` in the last try I did, which is a user_id, by a User Model object ? That's the error Laravel showed me, that I needed to replace that with a User Model object, but  Ididn't know how to.